# How to calculate current day value based on previous day, in pyspark?

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following scenario. On day o1, I have the balance, and day by day it is subtracting the transactions. I need to calculate the balance at the beginning and end of the day. I'm trying to use the lag function.

follows the logic in sql, remembering that it makes a loop to go through the whole month, always taking the previous ia and the current day

```
if month('day')=1 then
do;
begin_day = saldo + trans - vl_dis
+ vl_car + vl_ret;
end_day = saldo ;
end;
IF month('day')>1 then
do;
begin_day = end_day;
end_day = begin_day - trans
+ vl_dis - vl_car - vl_ret;
end;
```

output expected:

```
 +--------+--------+------+------+------+------+---------+--------+----------+
 | key    |   saldo| trans|vl_dis|vl_car|vl_ret|begin_day| end_day|       day|
 +--------+--------+------+------+------+------+---------+--------+----------+
 |123     |   100.0|   1.0|   2.0|   0.0|   0.0|     99.0|   100.0|2022-02-01|
 |123     |     0.0|   1.0|   0.0|   0.0|   0.0|    100.0|    99.0|2022-02-02|
 |123     |     0.0|   1.0|   0.0|   0.0|   0.0|     99.0|    98.0|2022-02-03|
 |123     |     0.0|   1.0|   0.0|   0.0|   0.0|     98.0|    97.0|2022-02-04|
 |123     |     0.0|   1.0|   2.0|   0.0|   0.0|     97.0|    98.0|2022-02-05|
 |123     |     0.0|   1.0|   0.0|   0.0|   0.0|     98.0|    97.0|2022-02-06|
 |123     |     0.0|   1.0|   0.0|   0.0|   0.0|     97.0|    96.0|2022-02-07|
 |123     |     0.0|   1.0|   2.0|   0.0|   0.0|     96.0|    97.0|2022-02-08|
 |123     |     0.0|   1.0|   0.0|   0.0|   0.0|     97.0|    96.0|2022-02-09|
 +--------+--------+------+------+------+------+---------+--------+----------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This when first looked at looks like a recursion problem as we have to keep looking back to value in previous row to calculate next value and recursive cte or tables are not supported in pyspark

But when looked closely this can be solved with running sum and lag so below first preparing the above data without start_day and end_day value which will be calculated with required imports

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql import Window

s=StringIO("""
key|saldo|trans|vl_dis|vl_car|vl_ret|day
123|100.0|1.0|2.0|0.0|0.0|2022-02-01
123|0.0|1.0|0.0|0.0|0.0|2022-02-02
123|0.0|1.0|0.0|0.0|0.0|2022-02-03
123|0.0|1.0|0.0|0.0|0.0|2022-02-04
123|0.0|1.0|2.0|0.0|0.0|2022-02-05
123|0.0|1.0|0.0|0.0|0.0|2022-02-06
123|0.0|1.0|0.0|0.0|0.0|2022-02-07
123|0.0|1.0|2.0|0.0|0.0|2022-02-08
123|0.0|1.0|0.0|0.0|0.0|2022-02-09""")

dfp=pd.read_csv(s,sep='|')
dfs=spark.createDataFrame(dfp)
```

Now below we will create the dataframe with the required start_day and end_day column

```
r_w=Window.partitionBy("month").orderBy("dom")
dfs.withColumn("month",F.month(F.col("day"))).\
withColumn("dom",F.date_format(F.col("day"), "d")).\
withColumn("trans_sum",F.sum("trans").over(r_w)-F.first("trans").over(r_w)).\
withColumn("vl_dis_sum",F.sum("vl_dis").over(r_w)-F.first("vl_dis").over(r_w)).\
withColumn("vl_car_sum",F.sum("vl_car").over(r_w)-F.first("vl_car").over(r_w)).\
withColumn("vl_ret_sum",F.sum("vl_ret").over(r_w)-F.first("vl_ret").over(r_w)).\
withColumn("start_day",F.when(F.col("dom")==1,F.col("saldo")+ F.col("trans")-F.col("vl_dis")+F.col("vl_car")+F.col("vl_ret")).otherwise(F.first("saldo").over(r_w)- F.lag(F.col("trans_sum"),1).over(r_w)+F.lag(F.col("vl_dis_sum"),1).over(r_w)-F.lag(F.col("vl_car_sum"),1).over(r_w)-F.lag(F.col("vl_ret_sum"),1).over(r_w))).\
withColumn("end_day",F.when(F.col("dom")==1,F.col("saldo")).otherwise(F.first("saldo").over(r_w)- F.col("trans_sum")+F.col("vl_dis_sum")-F.col("vl_car_sum")-F.col("vl_ret_sum"))).\
drop("month","dom","trans_sum","vl_car_sum","vl_dis_sum","vl_ret_sum").\
show()

#output
+---+-----+-----+------+------+------+----------+---------+-------+
|key|saldo|trans|vl_dis|vl_car|vl_ret|       day|start_day|end_day|
+---+-----+-----+------+------+------+----------+---------+-------+
|123|100.0|  1.0|   2.0|   0.0|   0.0|2022-02-01|     99.0|  100.0|
|123|  0.0|  1.0|   0.0|   0.0|   0.0|2022-02-02|    100.0|   99.0|
|123|  0.0|  1.0|   0.0|   0.0|   0.0|2022-02-03|     99.0|   98.0|
|123|  0.0|  1.0|   0.0|   0.0|   0.0|2022-02-04|     98.0|   97.0|
|123|  0.0|  1.0|   2.0|   0.0|   0.0|2022-02-05|     97.0|   98.0|
|123|  0.0|  1.0|   0.0|   0.0|   0.0|2022-02-06|     98.0|   97.0|
|123|  0.0|  1.0|   0.0|   0.0|   0.0|2022-02-07|     97.0|   96.0|
|123|  0.0|  1.0|   2.0|   0.0|   0.0|2022-02-08|     96.0|   97.0|
|123|  0.0|  1.0|   0.0|   0.0|   0.0|2022-02-09|     97.0|   96.0|
+---+-----+-----+------+------+------+----------+---------+-------+
```